# C++ WInApi thread

Tags: c++, winapi

on button "start" I doing thread

```
HANDLE  hThread1;
case butStart:
hThread1=CreateThread(NULL, 0, func_pressF1, NULL, NULL, NULL);
break;
case butStop:
//code
break;
```

how can I free thread on button stop? I think with this functions can help

```
VOID WINAPI ExitThread(
 __in DWORD dwExitCode
 );

 BOOL WINAPI GetExitCodeThread(
 __in HANDLE hThread,
 __out LPDWORD lpExitCode
 );
```

but I don't know what I must write here `__out LPDWORD lpExitCode`.
Maybe someone can write code for my example

Answer (score 4):

You should signal your thread to exit using some mechanism such as an event. After that the main thread should join the thread and then acquire the exit code (if needed). You should never force a thread to exit since resources might not get freed and mutexes might deadlock (if owned by the thread), for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try `WaitForSingleObject` to wait until the thread completes, `GetExitCodeThread` to get the exit code (or just use a global variable), then `CloseHandle` to free the handle.

`LPDWORD` is just the address (a pointer) of a `DWORD` variable.  Call like:

```
DWORD exit_code;
if (!GetExitCodeThread(hThread1, &exit_code)) // handle failure
```

Comment: I doing this http://i29.fastpic.ru/big/2012/0215/e5/52da11022468a9e9788fc8f032bd34e5.png
how I can free thread on"butStop" that then i can press "butStart" and it work

Comment: write please code, my english is bad and i not all understand what write here

Answer (score 0):

`__out LPDWORD lpExitCode` means that you are providing a pointer to a `DWORD` in which the function will place the exit code for you, like a second return-value!

```
DWORD ec;
GetExitCodeThread(hThread, &ec);
```

Comment: @Pavel You do not need to call ExitThread. It is enough to return from the thread function.

Comment: @Pavel: as others have said you should first call WaitForSingleObject/WaitForMultipleObjects. You can then call GetExitCodeThread, like i showed in my answer.

Comment: look. On "butStart" I must run thread, on "butStop" I must stop thread. I search this functions ResumeThread and SuspendThread

Answer (score 0):

`ExitThread` must be called by the thread itself. You can use `TerminateThread` which takes a thread-id as an argument and kills another thread.

Comment: It is not a good idea to use TerminateThread. For various reasons.

Comment: @rasmus: Generally I concur with you. But given nearly no information about the actual usecase I think it is better to have all options mentioned. Evaluation of the available options is the second step :-)